# Disabling SharePoint Rich Text field of a List inside a Div tag using Jquery

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am trying to hide the rich text field inside a div tag with a class name using jquery. The code I am using looks like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").children().find("#ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field").attr("disabled","disabled")
});
</script>​​<br/>​​​<br/>​<br/>​<br/>​​<br/>​​<br/>
```

inside "find" i am using the specified div class where my rich text field lies.Please help

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You need CSS to hide. You can use `display: none` to hide a element

```
$("div").children().find("#ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field").css({display :'none'});
```

To disable, try following

```
 $("div").children().find("#ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field").prop( "disabled", true );
```

**PS:** Above code should work if your selector is valid. See it works in [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/kahakukana/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thanks. but I need to disable the field not hide.

Comment: see my update ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `contenteditable` attribute to false to disable the field. Example:

```
$(".ms-rtefield div[role='textbox']").attr("contenteditable","false")
```